# como pasar el estado de un radio button de HTML a Js

Tags: javascript, html5

se que si pongo document.getElementBy('dato').checked; voy a poder ver si esta true o false

hora lo que quiero como se puede hacer enviando los datos desde el html

```
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" id='dato'>si
        <input type="radio" name="rad" >no
        <input type="button"  onclick="des()" >
    </form>
```

como se puede enviar el estado del radio desde onclick
¿como se debe enviar? desde el html
¿como se debería manipular en el js?

Comment: No crees que sería mejor escuchar el evento `submit` de tu formulario? Y así al ser enviado haces el `document.getElementById()`

Comment: El estado nunca lo _pasas_ a _js_. JavaScript no guarda el estado de los elementos, sino que tiene la posibilidad de verlo directamente usando el DOM, como parece que sabes: `document.getElementById()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Por el código asumo que la función des() (asociada al evento click del botón) es quien va a leer los valores del formulario.
El event.target es el botón y event.target.parentElement es el formulario, tanto event.target.parentElement.dato es el control con id=dato.
Si está o no marcado lo dice su propiedad checked, que es la que muestra concole.log dentro de des().
Creo que es la repuesta a lo que preguntas

```js
   
function des(){
  var o = event.target.parentElement.dato;
  console.log(o.checked);
}
```

```html
   <form>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" id="dato">si
        <input type="radio" name="rad">no
        <input type="button" onclick="des()">
    </form>
```